# Android SSL Connection

Tags: android, ssl, https, retrofit2, okhttp

Main task.
An attacker can not to conduct a man-in-the-middle attack intercepting transmitted data between a legitimate user and the application server.

Doing so:
But on android 4.4 get error (java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.).
If deleted section with pinning, then no error.
Tell me please, what do I doing not so?

```
public static Retrofit getClient() {

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

    private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
        try {
            // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            // Install the all-trusting trust manager
            final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            // Create an ssl socket factory with our all-trusting manager
            final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

            OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
            builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
            builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                @Override
                public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                    return true;
                }
            });

           //pinning
            CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
                    .add(BASE_URL, "sha256/aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
                    .build();

            final ConnectionSpec.Builder connectionSpec =
                    new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS);
            connectionSpec.tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2).build();

            TLSSocketFactory tlsSocketFactory;

            try {
                tlsSocketFactory = new TLSSocketFactory();
                builder.sslSocketFactory(tlsSocketFactory, tlsSocketFactory.systemDefaultTrustManager());
            } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            builder.certificatePinner(certificatePinner);
            //pinning

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
            builder.connectTimeout(TIMEOUT_HTTP, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            builder.readTimeout(TIMEOUT_HTTP, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            builder.writeTimeout(TIMEOUT_HTTP, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            return okHttpClient;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about version above 4.4 ?

Comment: rafsanahmad007, all ok

Comment: I did as here on first selution and helped
https://jiafei427.wordpress.com/2016/04/28/connect-to-server-with-self-signed-certificate-in-android-retrofit-or-okhttp/

I get certifacation for my server in format (.crt).
A certifacation can get on the website (https://www.ssllabs.com).